# Symfony override model getter with limit

Tags: symfony, model, limit, getter, redefine

Helo!

The autogenerated getter of the base model is getting more than 5000 rows per queries.

```
 modellClass->getNameList() // returns more than 5000 row
```

I am using echo_field to print the elements, which gets the result of getNameList()  as a paramter.

How can I override the deafault generated getter, to be able to set limit in the sql?

Ty

Answer (score 1):

You could filter the collection. It's described in the [Working with Associations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections) chapter of the doctrine docs.

If a collection wasn't fetched from the database yet, it'd work on a database level.

Other helpful links:

- [Add ability to filter a association](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-1007)
- [Filtering associations with Doctrine 2](http://www.boxuk.com/blog/filtering-associations-with-doctrine-2/)